# How to setup view in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've created an almost-empty UIViewController class named `MyViewController`. In the *viewDidLoad* I'm setting the title and adding a close-button to the *navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem*.

I'm presenting my `MyViewController` like this:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] myViewController];
nc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

When the viewController is presented, the background of it's view is just black. How can I setup it's view to fill-out the screen with an empty view -- just like when the UIViewController is setup in a Storyboard?

I've tried adding the following to the *viewDidLoad*, but the view is still black:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Comment: Are you sure the view's backgroundColor is white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a VC's view gets created in `-loadView` which you usually neither call, nor override. It gets called automatically the first time you request the the VC's `view` property.
The view's size is automatically set to the 'empty space', like everything except for the status bar without a NavigationController, minus the navbar when using one etc. You shouldn't worry about its size - usually it's just fine.

You can add your own views in `-viewDidLoad` and remove them again (for low-memory reasons) in `-viewDidUnload`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an UIImageView with custom image and then sent it to back 
So in your viewcontrollers `viewDidLoad`

```
UIImageView *back = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBG"]];
[self.view addSubview:back];
[self.view sendSubViewToBack:back];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a XIB file you should init the view controller through the method [initWithNibName: bundle:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a)